# Rails subclass method not overwriting the parent class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, overwrite

in `favors_controller` I have

```
private
def current_resource
    @favor ||= Favor.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
  end
end
```

and then in `application_controller` I have

```
 def current_permission
    @current_permission ||= Permission.new(current_user)
  end 

  def current_resource
    nil
  end

  def authorize
    if !current_permission.allow?(params[:controller], params[:action], current_resource)
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "No no no. You can't do that!"
    end
  end
```

The problem is that `current_resource` is nil. I tried putting `@favor ||= Favor.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]` directly in application controller and nothing changed! What do you think is the problem?

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `params[:id]` is not truthy, and therefore the `@favor ||= Favor.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]` statement is evaluating to `nil`

Comment: I just realized, that's true in `application_controller`, but in `favors_controller` it should work!

Comment: No, that's not how method calls work, the `params` method will work in either. Problem is that `params[:id]` is only defined for certain actions and the only thing that makes sense here is that the action where you're seeing this problem is an action that doesn't set the `:id` param, like `index`, `new` or `create`

Comment: Put a `raise` as the first line in your `FavorsController#current_resource` method and you'll confirm that it's being called.